# Sum of Quantities by Member

Tags: sql

Having some issues on a SQL statement for Wordpress.  Created a custom field "member_name" that gets held in order3 under key = member_name.  I need to create a report that shows the SUM of the quantity (held in order2 under key = "_qty") per member_name.

TABLES:

```
order1 - order1_id, order3_id 
order2 - order2_id, key, value
order3 - order3_id, key, value
```

EXAMPLE:

```
order1 
order1_id - order3_id 
2 - 292
3 - 292
4 - 281

order2 
order2_id - key - value 
2 - '_qty' - 1
3 - '_qty' - 2
4 - '_qty' - 1

order3 
order3_id - key - value 
292 - 'member_name' - John 
292 - 'member_name' - John 
281 - 'member_name' - Bill
```

DESIRED OUTCOME:

```
John 3
Bill 2
```

Here is what i'm working with:

```
SELECT order3.value, a.member_count 
FROM ((order3
INNER JOIN order3(select value, sum(*) as member_count
  FROM order2
  GROUP BY value
  WHERE order2.value='_qty') a
ON order3.order3_id=order1.order1_id)
INNER JOIN order2
ON order2.order2_id=order1.order1_id)
GROUP BY a.member_count
WHERE order3.key="member_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. It first gets the total `qty` value for each `order3_id`. Then, the name is looked up from the `order3` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o3.value,
    totals.total_qty
FROM order3 o3
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        o1.order3_id order3_id,
        sum(o2.value) total_qty
    FROM order2 o2
    INNER JOIN order1 o1 ON o2.order2_id = o1.order1_id AND o2.key = '_qty'
    GROUP BY o1.order3_id
) totals
ON o3.order3_id = totals.order3_id AND o3.key = 'member_name';
```

You can simply group by the name in order3 table. However, if 2 order3_id's have the same name, you would get unexpected results.